# Material UI DataGrid/DataGridPro performance issues with streaming data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I've been scouring the internet for recommended performance solutions in Material UI's DataGrid (I'm using DataGridPro) component and have not found any.

The DataGrid component seems to re-render all the way down to the cell level, every time the `rows` prop is updated.  I am using streaming/real-time data in my UI and updates are coming through up to 15x per second.  Many of these updates only affect one cell in the entire table, but it seems the entire table is re-rendered (including every cell). This is causing the UI to lock up and performance to degrade.

Are there any recommended ways to memoize cells and/or strategies for handling real-time data in the MUI DataGrid?